# How to create ActionController to get items with list of tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

Database tables, first table contain tags (id, name) the second table contain relation between items and tags.

```
  tags        
       id   name     
        1   TagA   
        2   TagB   
        3   TagC


 tags_items     
       item_id    tag_id
          1          1
          1          2
          1          3
          2          1
          2          3
```

Active reocrds :

```
  class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :tags_itemses

      validates_presence_of :name
      validates_length_of :name,  :maximum => 15
    end

    class TagsItems < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :tags
    end
```

In my controller i have index method:

```
def index
        items = TagItems.all.includes(:tags)
        render json: items,
               status: 200
      end
```

How the controller should looks like to get following json ?

```
    [{item_id :1, tags: [{id:1, name: TagA}, {id:2, name: TagB}, {id:3, name: TagC}]},
     {item_id :2, tags: [{id:1, name: TagA}, {id:3, name: TagC}]}]
```

Comment: What code have you already tried to produce the json?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the JSON output with the `include` option:

```
class TagsController
  def index
    items = TagItems.all.includes(:tags)
    render json: items, includes: {
       tags: {
         only: [:id, :name]
       }
     }, status: 200
  end
end
```

But this can get very repetitive though and bloats your controllers - [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) can help here.

**However** this will still not work since your modeling is way off! Models names should always be in singular! `tags_items` would be appropriate if it was a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship but that is a very special case since that is a join table without an associated model.

[image: gollum grammar]

What you want here is to use a `has_many :through` relationship to setup a many to many between tags and items:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_items # you're not Gollum!
  has_many :tags, through: :tag_items
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_items
  has_many :items, through: :tag_items
end

class TagItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :item
end
```

You also need to correct the name of the table! Create a migration with `rails g migration RenameTagsItems` and modify the contents:

```
class RenameTagsItemsMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :tags_items, :tag_items
  end
end
```

Then run the migration (`rake db:migrate`).